# cas+spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, cas, jasig

I'm trying to implement SSO in my app and as for now, I've faced the next problem:

```
HTTP Status 401 - Authentication Failed: Failed to provide a CAS service ticket to validate

type Status report

message Authentication Failed: Failed to provide a CAS service ticket to validate

description This request requires HTTP authentication (Authentication Failed: Failed to provide a CAS service ticket to validate).
```

I start my cas server on a different tomcat, login there and when I go to login pageat my app, then:
1. then is no autologin
2. when i enter credentials, I see the stacktrace shown above
I took an example from [this site](http://www.oudmaijer.com/2009/12/28/spring-3-spring-security-3-cas-3-3-4-integration/) .

here is my spring security context:

```
<security:global-method-security  pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

    <security:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true"
        entry-point-ref="casAuthenticationEntryPoint" >

    <security:custom-filter position="CAS_FILTER" ref="casAuthenticationFilter"></security:custom-filter>

        <security:access-denied-handler  ref="accessDeniedHandler" />

        <security:form-login login-page="/login.html"
            authentication-failure-url="/login.html?login_error=1"
            default-target-url="/index.html" 
            always-use-default-target="false"
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="failureHandler"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="successHandler" />
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login.html" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/member/**" access="hasRole('viewer')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('SiteAdmin')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('SystemAdmin')" />

        <security:remember-me />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService" />
        <security:authentication-provider ref="casAuthenticationProvider"></security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="myUserDetailsService"
        class="com.mypackage.MyUserDetailsService">
    </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.html" />
        <property name="forceHttps" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="successHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/member/index.html" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="failureHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login.html?error=auth_fail" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="bannedHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login.html?error=banned" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="accessDeniedHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl">
        <property name="errorPage" value="/403.jsp"></property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
        <property name="service" value="http://localhost:8080/spring-security-cas/j_spring_cas_security_check"></property>
        <property name="sendRenew" value="false"></property>
    </bean> 

    <bean id="casAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="casAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="loginUrl" value="http://localhost:9080/cas-server-webapp-3.4.10/login"></property>
        <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="casAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="myUserDetailsService"></property>
        <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties"></property>
        <property name="ticketValidator">
            <bean class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="http://localhost:9080/cas-server-webapp-3.4.10"></constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="key" value="cas"></property>
    </bean>
```

in web.xml, I've includede spring security context and set the appropriate listeners and etc.
in pom(I use maven) I've added the required dependencies, described in the article. 
But the problem stays.
I'd be glad any pieces of advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your error message "This request requires HTTP authentication" its seems, that your CAS server has authentication enabled. You need to deactivate that and login via a HTML-Page (i.e. it will be a JSP, ASP, or something similar).

Comment: how can I deactivate authentication in CAS? what is the logic?

Comment: Well, I used the examples from springsource: [link](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-security/tags/spring-security-3.0.0.RELEASE/samples) and started their CAS-Server using the command: `mvn jetty:run-war`. I just found a note that might be of more help to you: _import server certificate to the local keystore_ command `keytool.exe -importkeystore -srckeystore "spring-security-samples\certificates\server.jks" -destkeystore "%JAVA_HOME%\jre\security\cacerts"`

Comment: i installed the certicates beforehand... may be there is another reason?

Comment: As stated before, does your server require an authentication? When you directly navigate your browser to it (with a fresh session), does it ask for authentication before you see the CAS login-page?

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean, but I'll try to explain what I currently have. On the first tomcat I started CAS-server(I can login there and I see what ticket it gives me in console) and on the second tomcat I start my app, where I want to have SSO(single sign-on), thus I won't login, it should use the ticket, BUT it requires credentials, and after I put them in, I see the stacktrace above. So what steps I should perform?

Comment: Where does the request for credential comes from? Is it your app, or the CAS server (i.e. are you forwarded to the CAS)?

Comment: as I understand, the request must come from my app to CAS server, thus I should be forwarded to the CAS login page in case if I'm not logged in and to other pages if I already have a ticke. right?

Comment: Yes, that's how it should be. Are you forwarded when you browse your client-app? Is there a difference when you do not login upfront? Do you have cookies enabled? Have you imported all jars to the libs-folder?

Comment: no, I'm not forwarded to the CAS login page(despite of whether I'm logged in or not), I'm forwarded to my own login page, where I get this stacktrace, cookies are enabled. The last question - I don't understand. I just imported CAS-server.war file to my Eclipse workspace, there I just start it.

Comment: Your client app has a libs-folder, as for every web-app in `tomcat/webapps/<Appname>/WEB-INF/libs` - there you need to drop some .jar-files that contain essential classes (e.g. _cas-client-core-3.2.1.jar_). If you are not forwarded to CAS, there is more work to do... start at inspecting the clients log files (usually tomcat/logs/catalina.out).

Comment: I added there spring-security-cas-client.jar the version is as spring version(in my case it's 3.0.5.Release)

Comment: now I have 107 error code, I have already set up the server, but I get this error code. what's wrong?

Comment: I have disabled the certificates, both in the client app and on the CAS server... and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same trace,When

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But the cas login url don`t have the *.do suffix.When I add the .do it work well.